# How do I type this reduce callback?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, reduce

I'm trying to use reduce to create a simple CSV style header.

I have an array of objects that each have a 'title' parameter, and I want to reduce them to a single string with commas.

Here is my function:

```
     const colHeader: string = props.columns.reduce((curr: CustomColumn<T>, prev: CustomColumn<T>, index: number):string => {
 return index === 0 ? curr.title : prev.title + ","                                                                                                                  
  }, "")
```

The error I'm getting from the typescript compiler is that string and CustomColumn have no properties in common. It would be great if someone could explain how to type this correctly...

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you confused `prev` and `curr`, also the `prev` is a `string`.

```
interface CustomColumn<T> {
  title: string;
}

type T = string;

const colHeader: string = [{
  title: 'columnA',
}, {
  title: 'columnB',
}].reduce((prev: string, curr: CustomColumn<T>, index: number): string => index === 0 ? curr.title : prev + ", " + curr.title, "");

console.log(colHeader);
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMIFcDOYD2BbVHAG3TxAB4AVAPmQG8AoZZMYMIiALmWylAHMA3AwC+DBmACeABxSVkAXh5g+IIeIQ4Q2ZJqIAJCHAAm0brwGLkAbUbNW7LsgDke0iACCzgDSjv9JhY2Dm5XYncAIR9RAF0AOigIY3QkAApU6USAN3MVAX8EdCgobgxsfEISMipqf1BTAA9uEFIAI2gASlzVfkVaeogGxQUlAAZkAH5dIqg4hw5kbkyILOQAamQAIn9N9eniueCIHc2O4QZNbWIIOKIcflS9QxNO86A)

---

Also, the following is easier *(map to extract only the title, and join to create a string from the titles)*:

```
const colHeaderB: string = [{
  title: 'columnA',
}, {
  title: 'columnB',
}].map((x:CustomColumn<T>):string => x.title).join(', ');
```

Comment: Thank you very much -  I think I'll go with the map solution. As for the reduce, I think the issue might be to do with the typing of the columns. Thanks again

Comment: The `map` solution doesn't skip the first column, but @Raph117 your code does. Was skipping the first column unintentional? I agree with @Grégory that `reduce` probably isn't the right tool here (or indeed, almost anywhere else).

Answer (score 1):

The first parameter's type shouldn't be `CustomColumn<T>`, it should be `string`. That's the type of the accumulator, based on the initialization value you give for it (`""`) and what you're returning in the callback.

You also have an error in the callback, `curr.title` should just be `curr`:

```
return index === 0 ? curr : prev.title + ","                                                                                                                  
//                       ^−−−−− no `.title.`
```

So:

```
const colHeader: string = props.columns.reduce((curr: string, prev: CustomColumn<T>, index: number): string => {
    return index === 0 ? curr : prev.title + ","
}, "");
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=14&ssc=1&pln=17&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMIFcDOYD2BbVHAG3TxAB4AVAPmQG8BYAKGWTGDCIgC5lKBuZgF9mzBDhDZkAByg5pmZAF56zVuJJlMvANprW9Nhy68ARHFPIhAGn2s6Rzj2SmARpZt3D7J2YQfbFgMHHxMXABMA-QBdZDhFDGx8Qk0KbChQAHNqHWjhUSZxSTBkDQAJCDhw6F50rOUZOQUAOg1SSWaoCHD0JAAKPoR0KChasAyQTOtGiAA3XkTcAmJ2qmpp0GqAD14QUldoAEoxiczlWkYg1i6wYZBkTYgt5SUVAAZkAH5S4ahkXlkc2aoRQAGoXNZTMJpqZTIdBEwgA)

Having said that, you rarely need to explicitly type the parameters to inline callbacks like that. TypeScript is very good at inferring them:

```
const colHeader = props.columns.reduce((curr, prev, index) => {
    return index === 0 ? curr : prev.title + ","                                                                                                                  
}, "");
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMIFcDOYD2BbVHAG3TxAB4AVAPmQG8BYAKGWTGDCIgC5lKBuZgF9mzBDhDZkAByg5pmZAF56zVuJJlMvANprW9Nhy68ARHFPIhAGn2s6Rzj2SmARpZt3D7J2YQfbFgMHHxMXABMA-QBdZDhFDGx8Qk0KbChQAHNqHWjhUSZxSTBkDQAJCDhw6GUZOQUAOg1SSQaoCHD0JAAKboR0KChrOogAN2HQaoAPAEplWkYg1nawAZBkSYgp5SUVAAZkAH5SgahkXlkxhtCUAGoXa1NhYdNTGcEmIA)

---

Stepping back, though, this code skips the first column's title. And in general, `reduce` is almost never the tool to reach for (unless you're doing FP and passing a predefined function to `reduce`).

If you just want **all** of the titles, then as [Grégory NEUT says](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62537621/157247), use `map` and `join`:

```
const colHeader = props.columns.map(({title}) => title).join(",");
```

Again, TypeScript will infer the types just fine.

If you were skipping the first one intentionally, you could use `slice`:

```
const colHeader = props.columns.slice(1).map(({title}) => title).join(",");
```

Comment: @Raph117 - No worries. But out of curiousity, why are you skipping the first entry in the array? Is it not part of the header?